# Configure and link Excel to a delimited file for repeated use

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am dumping data in a tab delimited file that I would like to view and analyze in Excel.  But the file contents change frequently and I do not want to go through the importing steps every time, i.e. define delimiters, column names etc.  Is there a way to save a link metadata in an Excel file so that you can skip the definition steps upon subsequent openings, i.e. that it knows that the first row are column names, it is tab delimited etc.?

Thanks

Comment: If you turn on the Macro recorder while you do a fresh import it will record all the steps and settings.

Comment: I would think it would be easier/more appropriate to just "dump" the data in the correct format to begin with. Avoid "dumping" on your files.

Comment: @Stepan1010 -- it would not because my data dump occurs in a small Java program, from where it is easy to format the output in plain text.  it is possible to put it in Excel format but it would take a lot more work.

Comment: Ok, I understand you have your own reasons/circumstances. I always thought excel could open a TSV file(tab seperate value file) without going through the import process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Go through the Get External Data route. Once you set it up. All you have to do next is "Refresh Data". No macro needed.